# Upload Image with Json using Multipart

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I've tried different approach but still getting `stream was reset: NO_ERROR` response from `onFailure()` using Retrofit.

What is the correct way to implement this kind of setup?
[image]

This is what my APIService looks like:

```
@Multipart
    @POST(CREATE_STUDENT_RECORD)
    Call<CreateStudentResult> createStudentRecord(@Header(PARAM_TOKEN) String token, @Part("studentlist") RequestBody studentList,
                                                           @Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("type") RequestBody type);
```

And this is my API Call:

```
     RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), APIConstants.capturedImage);
    MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", APIConstants.capturedImage.getName(), requestBody);
    RequestBody type = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
            "Students");
    String studentList = new Gson().toJson(APIConstants.studentRecord);
    RequestBody students = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
            studentList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The image section isn't quite correct. You are sending a file of type "image/jpeg", so instead of:

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(
    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),
    APIConstants.capturedImage
);
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
    "image",
    APIConstants.capturedImage.getName(),
    requestBody
);
```

You want:

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(
    MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"),
    APIConstants.capturedImage
);
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
    "image",
    APIConstants.capturedImage.getName(),
    requestBody);
```

Comment: Tried that too but still not working.

Comment: Share the full stack trace of the error. If you have access to server-side maybe see what's happening on that end.